# Socket client, idle timeout

Tags: java, sockets

Is there anyway to set a timeout for a client socket if the client don't get/send any message in a certain time?

here is a sniplet of my code :

```
try {
  mainSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
  clientSocket = mainSocket.accept();
  in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
  out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

} catch (IOException ex) {
  Logger.error(this, "failed to accept connection. Error was " + ex.getMessage());
}

while (reading) {
  try {

    char[] arr = new char[2048];
    ch = 0;
    ch = in.read(arr);
    if (ch < 0) {
      reading = false;
    }
    else {
    //process message
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.error(this, ex);
  }
}
```

now what I want to do is if after x second the clientSocket didn't get any message, it will exit the loop, close the connection and restart accepting connection.

I know how to close the connection and restart accepting connection, but I still can't figure the rest. Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Thanks for the help